# Does selecting confounder variables for a model with multiple correlation tests risk biasing results (similar to forward selection)?

Tags: feature-selection, causality, overfitting, difference-in-difference, confounding

My team is conducting a counterfactual difference-in-differences (DiD) healthcare analysis to estimate the benefits of home nursing visits compared with a control group.

We've "pre-selected" variables by plotting a causal diagram, to eliminate mediators, colliders, etc.  Then, following the advice in [Zeldow & Hatfield (2021)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33978956/), we've identified confounders by conducting a series of correlation and interaction effect tests for "time-varying effect on the outcome or a time-varying difference between groups". Confirmed confounder variables are included in the DiD model.

**Question**: Could conducting a number of statistical tests on our analysis dataset in order to select confounder variables, followed by a model built with the **same data**, result in biased estimates of the treatment effect due to overfitting?

I'm worried we're, in effect, running a forward selection procedure. In order to avoid biased treatment effect estimators due to confounding, are we unwittingly trading one kind of bias for another?

Comment: Ultimately this may come down to a degrees of freedom question. In a simple regression model, if $k$ variables $X_1, X_2, . . ., X_k$ are being tested for confounding by estimating correlation between $X_i$ and treatment $A$ and $X_i$ and outcome $Y$, that's two extra degrees of freedom used per variable.

Comment: If you have the causal diagram, then you can positively identify confounders by whether they set up backdoor paths; in that case it only matters, I suppose, how you got your causal diagram. If you had a computer learn it via an algorithm such as is in Pearl's book *Causality*, then you might need to use other data to get the treatment effect. I'm not quite up on the ethics of re-using that data. If, on the other hand, you got the DAG from a subject matter expert, I don't see why you couldn't use the initial data to get the treatment effect.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Ok - you're arguing there's no need to run confounder tests if we know a priori based on the causal diagram from subject matter expertise. I didn't know there's an automated procedure for building a causal diagram. Is that possible given we don't know which direction causal arrows point if two variables are correlated?

Comment: How well a computer can learn a causal diagram is, as you say, limited to an extent. A computer can definitely learn the skeleton (nodes and undirected edges) and $v$-structure (location of colliders) of a DAG, given the right data. If switching any particular arrow's direction neither creates nor destroys a collider, then the computer will not be able to distinguish between those two possibilities. You'll need a SME to determine arrow directions, oftentimes.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: There are methods that, under extremely strong assumptions, can infer causal directions, see e.g. [here](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v6/mooij10a/mooij10a.pdf) for an overview. However, these are hardly ever practical and while there is some recent progress, many seemingly good results seem to be due to [flawed benchmarks](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2021/hash/e987eff4a7c7b7e580d659feb6f60c1a-Abstract.html).